# Draw Curve tool missing "Normal/View" option in 4.0

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to draw curves that connect to the faces of a mesh in 4.0, but I can't find the setting that allows me to do that; my only three options are Normal to Surface, Tangent to Surface, and View. I'm really at a loss as to why the Normal/View option isn't available

[image]